# Multiple similar elements, apply effects to single element at a time

Tags: jquery

Kindly check the following code. Its an auto generated code. I wish to apply fadeIn() effect to **"thumb-info"** class only.

```
<div class="work-thumbs">
<article>
<div class="thumb"><img src="1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="thumb-info">Link #1 - Heading #1</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="thumb"><img src="2.jpg" /></div>
<div class="thumb-info">Link #2 - Heading #2</div>
</article>
</div><!--/.work-thumbs-->
```

I have written the jQuery code as follows but it applies to all the elements in the list.

```
$('.thumb').mouseenter(function(){
$('thumb-class').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I want it to apply only to the element on which the cursor is hovering at the moment.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Thanks for your answers, but the **"thumb-info"** is a hidden element and on **".thumb"** hover only it will appear,so I cant use **thumb-info** class with **"this"** function. If that's what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your are selecting all the elements with class of `thumb-info`, you can use the `next()` or `siblings()` methods, try this:

```
$('.thumb').hover(function(){
     $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
     // or $(this).siblings('.thumb-info').fadeIn('slow');
},function(){
     $(this).next().fadeOut('slow');
     // or $(this).siblings('.thumb-info').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sv4Ea/)**

1. [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
2. [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
3. [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .hover() and pass in $this.

```
$('.thumb-info').hover(function() {
  $(this).dosomething //
});
```

By using `this` in your function handler, you are only effecting the element being hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` so that it doesn't apply it to all elements with that class.

```
$(".thumb").hover(function(){
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
},function(){
    $(this).next().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Can we hover over a hidden element!?